# Low quality video but high quality sound

Tags: youtube, video, audio

I am in France for the holiday, and the internet connection is not that great. Actually, I have to select 240p for my YouTube videos. I am following a YouTube course. While a poor video quality is acceptable, a poor audio quality is more of a problem.

Is there a way to have high quality audio despite low quality video on YouTube?

Comment: Why don't you mix the high quality audio with the low quality video wiht an video edit application? :D

Comment: @Manoochehr great idea. The OP must try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this isn't possible, seeing that the video and audio are linked when they stream. To get the highest quality sound you need the highest quality video.

<sub>Source: http://evolver.fm/2011/02/08/how-to-get-better-sound-on-youtube/</sub>